# AngularJS: service $http.get JSON file

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am very new to AngularJS. I have read several posts on this topic, but am still unable to get data from external JSON file.

here is my code

data.json

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": "20th August 2016",
        "day": "Sat",
        "in1": "10:30",
        "out1": "02:30",
        "in2": "04:00",
        "out2": "08:00",
        "in3": "",
        "out3": "",
        "total_hours": "8:00",
        "status": "1"
    },
    {   
        "id": 2,
        "date": "20th August 2016",
        "day": "Sat",
        "in1": "10:30",
        "out1": "02:30",
        "in2": "04:00",
        "out2": "08:00",
        "in3": "",
        "out3": "",
        "total_hours": "8:00",
        "status": "1"
    }
];
```

html

```
    <table ng-table="tctrl.tableEdit" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
       <tr ng-repeat="w in $data"  ng-class="{ 'active': w.$edit }">
          <td data-title="'ID'">
             <span ng-if="!w.$edit">{{ w.id }}</span>
             <div ng-if="w.$edit"><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="w.id" /></div>
          </td>
          ...
       </tr>                        
   </table>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('tableCtrl', function($filter, $sce, ngTableParams, tableService) {

     var data = tableService.data;

     //Editable
     this.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
     }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
     });

})
```

service.js

```
.service('tableService', [function($http){
        this.data = function() {
            return $http.get('data/timesheet.json');
        }
}])
```

I'm just trying to pull data from json file but it's not working and getting blank table. I don't know what is the issue. What I will get in `this.data`?

Comment: You are not invoking your function properly, try replacing this line `var data = tableService.data;` with this `var data = tableService.data();`

Comment: It's not working @svarog